# pick data from an array and place in an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to take out all objects in one array and put them under one object. Currently what I have is this

```
userData = [
{"key":"firstName","checked":true},
{"key":"lastName","checked":true},
{"key":"userName","checked":false},
{"key":"email","checked":false}
]
```

and using the code below

```
let results = {
   data: userData.forEach((k) =>({ ...k}))
}

console.log (results)
```

This gives me the below results

```
[
{"key":"firstName","checked":true},
{"key":"lastName","checked":true},
{"key":"userName","checked":false},
{"key":"email","checked":false}
]
```

but how I want to achieve the results, is this one below

```
{"firstName":{"key":"firstName", "checked":false},
"lastName":{"key":"lastName", "checked":false},
"username":{"key":"username", "checked":false}
"email":{"key":"email","checked":false},
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what `userData` contains. Also show what research you've done and any attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there you go.

```js
const userData = [
{"key":"firstName","checked":true},
{"key":"lastName","checked":true},
{"key":"userName","checked":false},
{"key":"email","checked":false}
]

const obj = userData.reduce((ac, cv) => ({...ac, [cv.key]: cv}), {})
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must go through the array and get key of the item to add it to the result

```js
const values = [
  {"key":"firstName","checked":true}, 
  {"key":"lastName","checked":true},
  {"key":"userName","checked":false},
  {"key":"email","checked":false}
]

const result = {}

values.forEach(value => {
  result[value.key] = value
})

console.log(result)
```